# Can infinitesimal changes of the limits on an integral change the value of the integral of a function, i.e., excluding delta-"functions" etc.?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

In other words, could $\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+}\int_\epsilon^\infty f(x)dx$ ever be different from $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$ when $f$ is a function and not a distribution in the Lebesgue sense.

Answer (score 1):

The limit could exist even though the integral from $0$ doesn't exist as a Lebesgue integral.  For example, $\displaystyle\int_0^1 \dfrac{\sin(1/x)}{x}\; dx$ does not exist as a Lebesgue integral, since $\displaystyle\int_0^1 \dfrac{|\sin(1/x)|}{x}\; dx = +\infty$, while $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0+} \int_\epsilon^1\dfrac{\sin(1/x)}{x}\; dx = \dfrac{\pi}{2} - Si(1)$$

Comment: Of course! Thanks.